# Iwant to add Radio button Image inside a pdf document Dynamically by replacing the content using content.replace("String","string menhod)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

```
protected void btnCreatePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create a Document object
    var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

    // Create a new PdfWrite object, writing the output to a MemoryStream
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

    // Open the Document for writing
    document.Open();

    // Read in the contents of the Receipt.htm HTML template file
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/HTMLTemplate/Receipt.htm"));

    // Replace the placeholders with the user-specified text
    contents = contents.Replace("[ORDERID]", txtOrderID.Text);
    contents = contents.Replace("[TOTALPRICE]", Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice.Text).ToString("c"));
    contents = contents.Replace("[ORDERDATE]", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    var itemsTable = @"<table><tr><th style=""font-weight: bold"">Item #</th><th style=""font-weight: bold"">Item Name</th><th style=""font-weight: bold"">Qty</th></tr>";
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in cblItemsPurchased.Items)
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            // Each CheckBoxList item has a value of ITEMNAME|ITEM#|QTY, so we split on | and pull these values out...
            var pieces = item.Value.Split("|".ToCharArray());
            itemsTable += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>",
                                        pieces[1], pieces[0], pieces[2]);
        }
    itemsTable += "</table>";

    contents = contents.Replace("[ITEMS]", itemsTable);


    var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), null);
    foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
        document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);



    // You can add additional elements to the document. Let's add an image in the upper right corner
    var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Images/4guysfromrolla.gif"));
    logo.SetAbsolutePosition(440, 800);
    document.Add(logo);

    document.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=Receipt-{0}.pdf", txtOrderID.Text));
    Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
}
```

There is a *.htm file which replaces the text content with string content ,but i want to add radio button checked or unchecked image there based on my data value.

Using this program as a base i created my code.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you shorten the code to focus on where your problem is?

Comment: Here in below mentioned code they are replacing html sting[OrderID] with datatable data ,similarly i want to replace them with an check box checked or un checked image ,based on condition.
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/HTMLTemplate/Receipt.htm"));

    // Replace the placeholders with the user-specified text
    contents = contents.Replace("[ORDERID]", txtOrderID.Text);
    contents = contents.Replace("[TOTALPRICE]", Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice.Text).ToString("c"));
ateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()); ,